# Алгоритм построения средней линии

Tags: алгоритм

Прошу простить, не позволено присоединять изображения, попробую описать словами.

Задача:
Имеется двумерный массив координат точек кривой. Кривая "дрожит". Усредненное направление кривой произвольно меняется, но при этом петли или пересечения образоваться не могут.   Необходимо получить усредненную кривую, для чего, как мне кажется, нужно получить кривые, проходящие через правые и левые пики исходной. А затем получить среднюю.
Может кто-то помочь алгоритмами?

Заранее благодарен за ответы.

Answer (score 2):

**Ответ переписан** с учётом 3-го комментария.

Так вам нужно отфильтровать «высокие частоты», Low Pass фильтр данных!

Я бы просто сделал размытие: каждую точку пересчитал как среднее арифм. набора из N соседних точек. N нужно подобрать с учётом ваших данных. Напр. для N=5:

[image: формула]

P.s. в векторных редакторах такая ф-я чаще всего уже есть. В Иллюстраторе точно.

Comment: Математическая модель, я думаю, займет не один том. Сложность в том, что кривая описывает границу среза поверхности земли, математика трудноприменима. То, что мне необходимо, похоже, на алгоритм векторизации растровой кривой по средней линии, но как работает векторизатор, для меня загадка. В статье по коэффициенту Пеарсона увидел близкие по смыслу изображения, поперевожу, может, поможет. :)

Comment: Вам же необходимо аппроксимировать зависимость кривой гладкой линией, а не линейной зависимостью. Или я чего-то не понял?

Comment: Правильно поняли. Не сообразил сразу так сделать.
Вот пример исходной кривой и увеличенного ее фрагмента.
http://www.hostimage.tk/upload_image/ec7023a5597f417d726004bd8ba94687.png
а вот то что я хочу получить(лиловая линия):
http://www.hostimage.tk/upload_image/f3839c08e91e89587688eac8b00472e9.png

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, то, что Вам необходимо, это сглаживающий сплайн (Носач В.В), особенно, если у Вас нет никаких соображений о математической модели процесса. К сожалению, программы в книге у Носача на Бэйсике.

Comment: Спасибо ответившим. В общем то я и сделал "скользящее среднее" который посоветовал Sergiks, но его результаты не всегда лежат в "выделенной полосе" так что есть еще к чему стремиться :)